# Using ITaskbarlist3 in an MDI application, (VC++ - MFC/Win32)

Tags: winapi, mfc, taskbar, dwm

I have been trying to incorporate the Windows 7 taskbar APIs in a regular MFC MDI (multiple document interface) application. I am using Visual Studio 2008 where I have redirected the SDK path to use the Windows 7 SDK.

The idea is to provide custom live preview bitmaps for each of the childframe windows that gets created inside the application. Though I have been able to make progress, there is a bit of struggle that I am going through with the final bits and pieces which do not seem to go right.Just wanted to know if I am missing anything.

Ok,

1. so we need a proxy window, which I have as the live preview APIs work only on top level windows (this is a disappointment). This window handles the WM_DWMSENDICONICTHUMBNAIL and WM_DWMSENDICONICLIVEPREVIEWBITMAP which provide the APIs with the required bitmaps for thumbnail preview and live preview.

   ```
   case  WM_DWMSENDICONICTHUMBNAIL:
       // get the bitmap of the client window
       // set it as thumbnail 
           width = HIWORD(lParam);
           height = LOWORD(lParam);
           hBitmap = CreateBitmapFromHandleAndResize(hwnd, width, height);
           if (hBitmap)
           {
               SetThumbnail(hBitmap, hwnd);
               DeleteObject(hBitmap);
           }
       break;
   case WM_DWMSENDICONICLIVEPREVIEWBITMAP:
           hBitmap = CreateBitmapFromHandle(hwnd);
           if (hBitmap)
           {
               SetThumbnailForPreview(hBitmap, hwnd);
               DeleteObject(hBitmap);
           }
           break;
   ```
2. Both the functions CreateBitmapFromHandleAndResize and CreateBitmapFromHandle create a DIB aka device independent bitmap which are food for the APIs DwmSetIconicThumbnail and DwmSetIconicLivePreviewBitmap.

Problem faced:
The problem I am facing is in the live preview bitmap area where the following code does the work. The hBitmap is a 32 bit depth DIB which when saved on the disk seems to be a proper screenshot of the child window that I would like to display. But when I preview it, somehow the title bar and the bitmap doesn't seem to be of the same quality as of the window itself. In fact it looks like an out of focus representation of the child window. I would like to have the same quality image displayed because the user should not feel the difference.

Currently I take the print of the entire window including the frame and position the live preview exactly on top of the existing window so that when the live preview is on, the user is deceived to see the bitmaps instead of actual child windows.

I hope this is the expected behaviour here of live preview. Please let me know if I am wrong here.

One other problem was the offset. Not sure whether I am doing something wrong here. But it simply does not work when I just do a diff of the two rects. The correction factor of 8 and 14 was done with a trial and error method!

```
    void SetThumbnailForPreview(HBITMAP hBitmap, HWND hWnd)
    {
     StateInfo *pState = (StateInfo *)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA);

         CWnd* pMainFrame = pState->m_pParentWnd->GetParent();

         pState->pTaskBar->SetTabActive(hWnd, pMainFrame->GetSafeHwnd(), 0);

         RECT rectClient, rectMainframe;
         pState->m_pParentWnd->GetClientRect(&rectClient);
         pState->m_pParentWnd->ClientToScreen(&rectClient);

         pMainFrame->GetWindowRect(&rectMainframe);

         POINT offset;
         offset.x = (rectClient.left - rectMainframe.left) - 8;
         offset.y = (rectClient.top - rectMainframe.top) + 14;

         HRESULT hr = DwmSetIconicLivePreviewBitmap(hWnd, hBitmap, &offset, 0);
       }
```

My questions in a nutshell:

1. Is there anyway to get the bitmap being displayed with the same quality as that of the window itself so that no difference is being felt.
2. Is the offset calculation correct. Why does it not work with straightforward RECT diffs?
3. Whether my understanding is correct with respect to the behaviour of live preview in an MDI app

   **In the thumbnail preview area:**
   The the MDI main window is always displayed along with the other thumbnails. The
   thumbnail images are individual representations of the child windows.

   **In the live preview area:**
   If you hover over individual thumbnails, the live preview always displays the MDI main
   frame along with the child windows. The difference here is that the user gets to see
   that  particular child window (the one that the hover is on) getting the focus and highlight.
4. Am I doing the correct thing here or are there some additional things that I am not aware of?

Thanks in advance!
Ranjit

Comment: Interesting that you say the live preview only works with top level Windows, it must be possible as IE9+ does it... Good luck